# Mail merge, using my own fields: .xls, word 2003 xp pro

Tags: microsoft-word-2003, mail-merge

Office Version:Office 2003Operating System:Windows XP
0
I have a Word doc that looks like this:

```
<<PracticeName>>

<<PracticeAddress>> 

<<PracticeCitystate>>

<<PatientName>>

<<PatientAddress>>
```

And a .xls that looks like this:

```
PracticeName        PracticeAddress    PracticeCitystate     PatientName    PatientAddress

Acme Diagnostics    101 Apian Road     Cleveland, OH 44115   George Bush    111 Broad Way
```

I have Word 2003 and I:

- Open Word & blank doc
- > Tools>Letters&Mailings>MailMerge
- Letters is checked>Next
- Check "Start from existing," and
  select my aforementioned doc, open>Next
- Check "Use an existing list," and
  open my aforementioned xls, open, use
  defaults > Next
- Do nothing at "write    your letter" > Next

OK, I'm at preview, yet my document still looks exactly as shown above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While jet's answer probably will apply to many cases, my problem was that I had typed the "<<" and ">>" brackets manually. You can't do that. You have to use the "Insert Merge Fields" dialogue.

See [here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wordshare/thread/f4037804-5574-44d4-9ac8-9d36c809082b/#9d34b44a-9dce-4c39-8c3a-4c74ea2e6d0f) for those that might find themselves in the same boat.

Answer (score 1):

don't go to preview mode

there should be a button View Merged Data - looks like << >> ABC

it alternatively switches between template and data views

also you should use the button "insert merge field" instead of two << - this is a single symbol